# Pytorch - What module should I use to multiply the output of a layer using Sequential?

Tags: python, pytorch

While defining a neural network using *nn.Module*, in the forward function I can multiply the output of the final layer using:

```
def forward(self, x):
    ...
    x = torch.mul(x, self.max_action)
    return x
```

I am trying to do the same but instead using *nn.Sequential* method to define the neural network

```
model = nn.Sequential()
model.add_module(...
...
model.add_module(name='activation_output', module=?)
```

What should I use there to have the previous layer multiply by the scalar *self.max_action* ?
Or should I build the sequential model in a different way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a custom [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) layer:

```
class Multiply(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, alpha):
        super().__init__()
        self.alpha =  alpha
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.mul(x, self.alpha)
        return x
```

Then use it as:

```
>>> model = nn.Sequential()
>>> model.add_module(name='activation_output', module=Multiply(10))

>>> model(torch.ones(1))
tensor([10.])
```

Comment: It is crazy that pytorch is missing these super-basic layers.

Comment: There is no much point of introducing this kind of native operation in the built-in library since these can be easily performed on the fly since PyTorch is functional.